# How to set the default result set of Oracle APEX form to be empty?

Tags: oracle-apex

When accessing an Oracle APEX form, the form automatically returns a set of results.

Is there a way to make the default/initial result set of a form to be empty?
I want the users to see nothing when they visit the page and I want the users to use the search bar to search for the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want the clear cache parameter in the URL to be the page number, clearing out session state for all your page items.

http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/understanding-url-syntax.htm#GUID-F249FDCA-972B-4DFB-A51B-DD127AAB9C35

Adjust this in the navigation link to the page.

Alternatively, you can define a calculation, or set the source of the relevant items to always be null.